# cannot modify frame of UIImageView if added through Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uiimageview, interface-builder

I came across this very peculiar problem where I am unable to modify the frame of a UIImageView.

I have isolated it to this very simple example. Starting from a default single view application xcode template, I add a UIImageView in Interface Builder, link it to the ViewController property called testImage, and in ViewController.m I add:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    UIImageView* maskImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.testImage.frame];
    maskImage.image = self.testImage.image;
    maskImage.alpha = 0;
    [self.view addSubview:maskImage];
    self.testImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
}
```

and it does not work. The test image remains resolutely where it was. If I do not add maskImage to view, the example works. And, yes I am sure I am not covering the destination with maskImage.

If I do not use the IB to place the image, but instead use:

```
self.testImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 300, 300)];
self.testImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"jim-105.png"];
[self.view addSubview:self.testImage];
```

in viewDidLoad it all works as expected.

I have also tried to just place the image in IB, then set its properties in viewDidLoad, but with the same effect. I have been trying this in Xcode5. I do not have access to previous Xcode here, and I am not sure is this an expected behaviour (and if so why) or is this a bug?

Comment: In your first example, is `self.testImage` nil?

Comment: No, it is not. I set it in IB.

Comment: If you add `NSLog(@"testImage: %@", self.testImage);` before and after the last line in the `viewDidAppear` method, what does it show?

Comment: testImage: <UIImageView: 0x9982160; frame = (0 100; 300 300); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9982010>>

testImage: <UIImageView: 0x9982160; frame = (10 10; 10 10); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9982010>>

But the image remains where it was on screen...

I can change it's other properties. For example if i change it's contentMode or backgroundColor it is shown as expected.

Comment: I have reworked the example from scratch. Now i do have autolayout (as I do in my original app where I first experienced this). I have also placed constraints in IB to testImageViw as well. And the code behaves the same. If I do not add the maskImage using addSubview, the test image resizes. What confuses me is that one of these is not right. It either obeys the constraints or not. Why would it only obey constraints if I add a sibling to superview?

Comment: It's not that it only obeys constraints in that scenario, but rather that changing a `frame` is not enough to trigger the constraints to be reapplied.  Constraints are reapplied only when you add views, change the content of views that have intrinsic size, manually call `layoutIfNeeded`, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd expect precisely the behavior you describe if you were using auto layout, in which attempts to adjust the `frame` can be thwarted when constraints are reapplied (which can happen with the most incidental of events, such as adding another view to the main view) and the `frame` will be recalculated. If you have an autolayout view with constraints, to change its size you change its constraints.

If you're wondering why the programmatically created `testImage` works as expected, it's because by default, the programmatically created view has `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` turned on. Thus, attempts to change the `frame` persist.

If you're using autolayout and want to change the `frame`, you can accomplish this by adding `IBOutlet` references for the constraints in Interface Builder. Let's say you had top, leading, width and height constraints for your view. You could then change it's frame (in this example, to `CGRect(0, 100, 300, 200)`) with:

```
self.imageViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 0;
self.imageViewTopConstraint.constant = 300.0;
self.imageViewWidthConstraint.constant = 300;
self.imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = 200;
```

Clearly, you need those four `IBOutlet` references, but once you do that, it's quite easy.

Comment: No I do not use auto layout. And even If I do, the example works just fine if I do not add a maskView. Adding a copy of the UIImageView makes it to stick. And that only if I add the original image in IB.

Comment: @nekiTamoTip If you have autolayout on, when you add `maskImage`, the constraints may be reapplied, and the `frame` for `testImage` will be recalculated. For the IB-added `testImage`, that means it returns to the original location. For the `testImage` that you created in code, you have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` turned on (as it is by default), so the new `frame` will work. And for me, with auto layout off, your code works fine with the `testImage` added in IB.

Comment: Thanks very much Rob, this explanation really helped me.