# I create an UIImage view in interface builder, how to change its frame (position&size) in code?

Tags: ios, layout

I have made the following changes in code for the image view, but it doesn't take effect at all. I think the key things is I created the image view in IB instead of in code.

```
userInfoBackground.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100);
userInfoBackground.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

What shall I do next? Thanks.

Comment: this seems a duplicate questions here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066880/cannot-modify-frame-of-uiimageview-if-added-through-interface-builder.  However, I find a new way inspired by the answer above, setting the image views property "translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints"to YES  would solve the issue so far. It is the simplest way but not sure if it is danger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It never effect, that is your choice you can create imageview by code or by IB.
You are facing this issue due to autolayout. In interface builder document(right hand side) uncheck the autolayout option and then your code will work.